# Csv empty when trying to read it

Tags: csv, go

Here is my code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "encoding/csv"
)




func main() {

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Printf("Error: Source file name is required\n")
        fmt.Println("Usage:", os.Args[0], "<filename> \n")
        return
    }

    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }
    // deferred call to Close() at the end of current method
    defer file.Close()
    //get a new cvsReader for reading file
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    //Configure reader options Ref http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/csv/reader.go?s=#L81
    reader.Comma = '|'
    reader.Comment = '#'        //Comment character
    reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1 //Number of records per record. Set to Negative value for variable
    reader.TrimLeadingSpace = true

    record, err := reader.Read()
    fmt.Println(record)
    result, _ := reader.ReadAll()
    fmt.Println(result)
    for i := range result {
        // Element count.
        fmt.Printf("Elements: %v", len(result[i]))
        fmt.Println()
        // Elements.
        fmt.Println(result[i])
    }

}
```

And the csv is like this :

```
<iframe src="http://www.testdata.com/embed/ph5721952ef0c4e" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>|http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)14.jpg|http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)1.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)2.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)3.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)4.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)5.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)6.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)7.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)8.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)9.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)10.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)11.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)12.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)13.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)14.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)15.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)16.jpg| it's done|allhomedata;hardware;wf;couple;ITwjob;dsshot;small-tera;forceager;wf;tamed-cat;bg-wf-chicken;cowanimal;tracy-rod;tamed;ds-on-table|wf;dsshots;Hardware;force||976|51703|122|40
<iframe src="http://www.testdata.com/embed/ph5721952ef0c4e" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>|http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)14.jpg|http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)1.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)2.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)3.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)4.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)5.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)6.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)7.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)8.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)9.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)10.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)11.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)12.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)13.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)14.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)15.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)16.jpg| it's done|allhomedata;hardware;wf;couple;ITwjob;dsshot;small-tera;forceager;wf;tamed-cat;bg-wf-chicken;cowanimal;tracy-rod;tamed;ds-on-table|wf;dsshots;Hardware;force||976|51703|122|40
<iframe src="http://www.testdata.com/embed/ph5721952ef0c4e" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>|http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)14.jpg|http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)1.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)2.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)3.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)4.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)5.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)6.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)7.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)8.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)9.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)10.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)11.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)12.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)13.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)14.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)15.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)16.jpg| it's done|allhomedata;hardware;wf;couple;ITwjob;dsshot;small-tera;forceager;wf;tamed-cat;bg-wf-chicken;cowanimal;tracy-rod;tamed;ds-on-table|wf;dsshots;Hardware;force||976|51703|122|40
<iframe src="http://www.testdata.com/embed/ph5721952ef0c4e" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>|http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)14.jpg|http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)1.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)2.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)3.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)4.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)5.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)6.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)7.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)8.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)9.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)10.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)11.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)12.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)13.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)14.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)15.jpg;http://i0.cdn2b.image.testdata.zhncdn.com/videos/201604/28/75158391/original/(m=eaf88daaaa)16.jpg| it's done|allhomedata;hardware;wf;couple;ITwjob;dsshot;small-tera;forceager;wf;tamed-cat;bg-wf-chicken;cowanimal;tracy-rod;tamed;ds-on-table|wf;dsshots;Hardware;force||976|51703|122|40
```

but the output is like :
    []
    []

i don't understand why the [] appear ....
If anyone have any idea why the file reading appears to be empty.

Seems that the reading process seems to be broken.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is you're not checking errors, at least in the example you're not. If you check the error returned from reader.Read() you would know that it is [ErrBareQuote](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#pkg-variables), to avoid that error you have to set the [csv.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader)'s LazyQuotes field to true. Here's a working version of your code https://play.golang.org/p/3y-T1DCsp6